# ReactJS/nextjs Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I made a small application for learning purposes where you have a contact book and you can add and remove new contacts. Everything works fine, I have all functionality on one page. This is my code:

index

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import ContactList from '../components/ContactList'
import AddContact from '../components/AddContact'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import uuid from 'react-uuid'

export default function Home() {
  const LOCA_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    console.log(contact)
    setContacts([...contacts, {id: uuid(), ...contact}]);
  }

  const removeContactHandler = (id) => {
    const newContactList = contacts.filter((contact) => {
      return contact.id !== id;
    });
    setContacts(newContactList);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCA_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts)));
    if(retrieveContacts) setContacts(retrieveContacts);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCA_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
  }, [contacts]);
  
  return (
    <>
    <Header />
    
    <div className={styles.container}>
      
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} getContactId={removeContactHandler}/>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

As simple as it is Im using `useEffect` to render the values and im saving everything in `localstorage`. Inside my `AddContact` component I'm calling `props.addContactHandler(contact)` after user filled in contact data.

Now I wanted to create a new page called `/add-contact` and put the form and functionality from `AddContact` there, but im not able to access `props.addContactHandler` or to me more precise: I cant do the `setContacts` `useState()` . I didnt find a way to call the function except marking it as export function and place it above my `export default function Home()`. I tried several things but im always ending up in NextJs invalid hook call. Can somebody guide me to the correct solution? How to access `addContactHandler` and change state correct?

add-contact.js (copied from AddContact Component which I deleted, since I want to have the code on its own page)

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


export default function AddContact(props) {
    
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const router = useRouter();

     function add(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(name === "" || email === ""){
            alert('Fehler beim Ausfüllen der Felder');
            return;
        }

        
        setEmail('');
        setName('');
        // Here im getting stuck <---------
        props.addContactHandler({name,email})
        router.push({
            pathname: '/',
          })
    }

    return (
        <>
        <form onSubmit={add}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="name" value={name} onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}}  />
            <input type="text" placeholder="email" value={email} onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}} />
            <button>Kontakt hinzufügen</button>
        </form>
        </>
    );
  }
```

ContactList.js

```
import ContactCard from '../components/ContactCard'
import Link from 'next/link'
import router from 'next/router'

export default function ContactList( props ) {
   
    const deleteContactHanlder = (id) => {
        props.getContactId(id)
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div class="main-container">
        <div class="left">
        <h1>Contact List</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="rigth">
            
        <Link href="/add-contact"><a style={{
            "font-size": "16px",
            background: "#7373b5",    
            color: "white",    
            padding: "0.4em 1.5em",    
            
            }}>Kontakt hinzufügen</a></Link>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        
        {props.contacts.map((contact) =>(
            <ContactCard contact={contact} clickHandler={deleteContactHanlder}/>
        ))}


        </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: You telling us that you can't access some function without showing the component which uses it, please make a full reproducible example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hello Dennis, excuse me, I didn't share the add-contact.js and component. Its updated now

Comment: where is the `useBetween` used?

Comment: I tried usebetween in an earlier version, I didnt remove it yet, im sorry. Should be more clear now

Comment: `addContactHandler` decleared at `Home`. how it should arrive into new page props?

Comment: Im not sure.. if i mark the function as export function i cant access the state.. (sorry im still quite new)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yesterday I fixed my issue and I hope that I can prevent some other people for this silly thing. Basically I started using the library [use-between](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-between) to share my states across the pages. In this way I was able to place the `addContactHandler` on my newly created page.

Now every time I created some data, my list was empty. I figured out, that my `useEffect` functions which are in `/pages/index/` weren't high enough in my structure. I fixed the issue by placing those 2 hooks in my `_app.js` since from there we are showing every kind of page.

By the way: I stumbled over `use-between` randomly. Are there similar ways to solve this?